# spring roo model binding without validation

Tags: validation, spring-roo

Here is my model `Admin` :

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Admin {

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Timestamp createTime;

    @Transactional
    public void persist(){
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.password = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(this.password);
        this.createTime = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        this.entityManager.persist(this);
    }

}
```

The `createTime` field is a bit different that from a DB's view this field cannot be null because future business logic may refer to it , but from a user's view it never appears in `create admin form` because it will be filled by `persist` code later. The problem is that `AdminController.create` failed validating the new created `Admin` object because at this point `createTime` is still `null`.

So What can I do to make the creation of an `Admin` success?

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid the @NotNull in the Entity (Admin)

It's only for the creation of the objects. If every object is obtained from the database, except the ones to be created (either in the web form or in the tests via DataOnDemand), it won't be a problem for the application.

Comment: It's not only for the creation of the objects. It will affect the generated db schema. Removing this annotation allow creation of objects but it's unsafe because `persist` may not be the only way to insert record into the table. DBA may insert rows directly, for example.